# Hi I would like to run a loop from a list and have it go through a function one at a time using R?

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a dataframe(df) that looks like this

```
  a|    b|    c|    d|    e|    f
val1 val2 val3  val4   val5  val6
```

my list is

```
 list<-c("b","c","d")
```

I want it so that only b,c, and d run through a function trimws. However it can be anything.

```
for (i in list) {
  assign(df, get(df) %>% trimws (i), envir = .GlobalEnv)}
```

I tried running this loop but it did not work. I received an error message

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "  assign(df, get(df) %>% trimws (i), envir = .GlobalEnv)}"
```

At the end of the day i want to run a function specifically in the three columns only and for it to ignore the ones not in the list

Comment: The closing `}` of your loop needs to be on a new line. That is what that error means.

Comment: `df[c("b", "c", "d")] <- lapply(df[c("b", "c", "d")], trimws)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you complete a working loop to build from. This should help you with skipping certain values.

```
    list <- c("b","c","d")

    Output <- NULL

    for(i in list){
        if(i == "c"){next}
        
        Output <- c(Output, i)
    }
Output
[1] "b" "d"
```

Comment: No i want to run the loop on df where  it only runs  on columns "b","c", and "d" based on the list i created.

Comment: `df[c("b", "c", "d")] <- lapply(df[c("b", "c", "d")], trimws)`.